# Problema con triggers en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

bueno soy bastante nueva utilizando mysql, estoy tratando de crear un trigger el cual no permita hacer mas de 3 registros en una tabla, pero me arroja muchos errores de falta de ; y cosas así, he seguido varios ejemplos pero no doy con una solución :c

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1_MAXIMO_PROFESOR 
BEFORE INSERT ON SGS_IMPARTE 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE RUT INT; 
    SELECT COUNT(NEW:SP_PROFESOR) 
        INTO RUT
            FROM SGS_IMPARTE;

    IF RUT<=3 THEN 
         INSERT INTO SGS_IMPARTE(SP_PROFESOR,SA_ID) VALUES (NEW:SP_PROFESOR,NEW:SA_ID);
    ELSE 
         signal sqlstate '-20000' set message_text = 'Error, ya hay  3 registros!';
end if;
end;$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que estás intentando algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1_MAXIMO_PROFESOR 
BEFORE INSERT ON SGS_IMPARTE 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE RUT INT; 
    SELECT COUNT(NEW.SP_PROFESOR) 
        INTO RUT
            FROM SGS_IMPARTE;

    IF RUT>=3 THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '20000' 
          set MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error, ya hay  3 registros!';
    end if;
end;
```

Para el dataset de pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE SGS_IMPARTE(
    SP_PROFESOR int,
    SA_ID int
  );
```

Al cuarto intento de:

```
INSERT INTO sgs_imparte (SP_PROFESOR, SA_ID)
  VALUES (1,1);
```

Te dará error y no te permitirá insertar el dato.

Tan sólo había tres errores:

- Utilizabas el `NEW.campo` con `:` en vez de `.`
- Utilizabas un número negativo para el código del error `20000`
- Intentabas repetir el `INSERT` dentro del disparador. Lo cual no es necesario porque es lo que se hará sin especificarlo y, además, da error, porque el disparador volvería a lanzarse indefinidamente por la referencia circular.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: sii, gracias ya lo solucione, añadir que me faltaban los delimiter al inicio y fin, y que para el caso se necesitaba de un after en vez de before. Gracias!!

Comment: Genial, entonces no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)